# Checking if a letter is capitalized or not in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a string stored in a variable stuff

```
.data          
     stuff: .ascii    "lol\n"
```

and I want to check if the letters are capitalized or not, "l" or "L" but my comparison doesn't work

```
movl $stuff, %ecx   
movl (%ecx), %eax

cmp $0x41, %eax              #compara com "A"
jl next
```

What am I doing wrong in the comparison? And no, the code is not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>If you are debugging assembly language, you are going to have to learn how to use a debugger.  There is a million little things that may be going wrong at any moment with your code, it will be very time consuming to solve a million little things one little thing at a time by posting a question for each on stackoverflow.</sup>

You are using a `movl` instruction to load the contents of the memory address pointed by `ecx` into `eax`.  Now, `eax` is a 32-bit register, so you are loading 32 bits from that memory address.  32 bits are 4 bytes.  The `stuff` memory location is defined as `.ascii`, so it contains bytes.  So, you are loading the entire "lol" and the linefeed following it into `eax`, that will be some huge number like `0x0d6d6f6d`, and then you are comparing that against `0x41`, which obviously will not work.

You need to load a single byte from the memory location pointed by `ecx`, not 4 bytes.  (Either that, or you need to store "l", "o", "l" and "\n" in separate doublewords, but that would be wasteful.)

Comment: So how can I move just one byte?

Comment: There is a number of ways to do that; one is to first load 0 into `eax` and then load the contents of the memory location pointed by `ecx` into the 8-bit register `al`, which is the first of the four bytes that make up `eax`.

Comment: The only thing that needs to change here is the encoding of the `cmp` instruction: `cmpb $0x41, %al`. That will do exactly what @codetective wants, comparing a single byte (the first low-order character) from `EAX`. Now, you could then say that loading the full 8 bytes is wasteful, and that would be true if you only ever wanted to inspect the first character. But if subsequent code (on either side of the branch) might want to look at characters/bytes 2–4, then you're better off doing a 32-bit load.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ASCII is being used you can determine if it is an uppercase character by testing bit 5.

```
Char 'A' = 65 = 0100 0001
Char 'a' = 97 = 0110 0001
```

So all you need is a simple bit test

in your example code it looks like you are attempting to compare all characters to see if they are the character A which is only going to work if the character in the message is litterally the character A, and not for any other character.